# AutoIt or batch for FTP transfer to on multiple servers

Tags: batch-file, autoit

I must log in to multiple servers and upload some files. Is there a chance to code this with AutoIt?

I have tested it with an batch file, but doesn't work:

```
echo open < /FTP/ftphost.txt   
echo < /FTP/ftpuser.txt    
echo < /FTP/ftppass.txt    
echo cd C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator\Desktop\FTP\dateien>>ftp.txt    
echo cd httpdocs>>ftp.txt     
echo mput test.txt test2.txt   
echo bye
```

p
    in the ftphost.txt File should be the diffrent FTP Servers
    in the ftpuser.txt file the diffrent ftp users
    in the ftppass.txt file one password.

Comment: Your script can create three FTP scripts and run them in succession.  Is there a reason why that is not an option?

Comment: hmm i need 50-100 connections.
the script doesnt work, you know why ?

Comment: Windows FTP only does one connection at a time.  You may be able to run more than one FTP script at a time, though, I haven't tried it. 50-100 is a bit on the high side as a cmd prompt will have to run for each FTP connection.

Comment: This is ok, but the script should work through the list of ftphost.txt

Script doesnt work for 1 connection.

Comment: More information is needed to create a working script.  Are you uploading the same file to 100 FTP hosts?

Comment: Yes, but they are 3-5 files. 1 index.html and pictures.

Comment: `ftp.host1.com|username1|password1` <-- can you create a file with this information, one line per FTP host?  In `server|username|password`  pipe separated format.  Is the folder structure on each server the same?

Comment: yes i upload all files in folder /httpdocs

Comment: Check out this autoit UDF. I'm a big autoit fan. This should help do what you want.http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/78378-ftp-udf-updated-1-10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a file with the FTP information like this (and each FTP server has the same folder structure)

`FTPlist.txt`

```
ftp.host1.com|username1|password1
ftp.host2.com|username2|password2
ftp.host3.com|username3|password3
ftp.host4.com|username4|password4
```

Then this batch file can upload the set of files to each FTP server:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=|" %%a in ("FTPlist.txt") do (
(
echo.open %%a
echo.%%b
echo.%%c
echo.binary
echo.lcd "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Administrator\Desktop\FTP\dateien"
echo.cd httpdocs
echo.mput test.txt test2.txt   
echo.bye 
) >ftp.script
ftp -i -s:ftp.script >> ftp.log
)
del ftp.script
```

Comment: Thanks for the Script, but it doesnt work :(
Is there a chance to get an log file, to see the error?

Comment: I added a FTP.log creation.

Comment: i have deleted the line, but i can see the window 1/2 second and then it closes.

Comment: try the code now.  I edited it earlier and you may have gotten a typo in yours.  Open a cmd prompt and then launch the batch file - you will see any errors from the batch file, but not from the FTP sessions as it is being redirected into the log now.

Comment: Ah yes, very nice job ! Thanks. it was the zonealarm :(